# Windows 10 Pro getting half the original internet speed

Tags: windows-10, networking, internet, internet-connection, internet-speed

My PC suddenly started only getting at maximum 300Mbps (mostly 270Mbps), while every other computer on the network gets 500Mbps.

The same cable on the same switch on another computer gets the 500Mbps, only my desktop doesn't even reach 300Mbps.

Already tried answers from other questions and no luck, sometimes even got worse results.

My motherboard is Asus ROG STRIX X470-F Gaming.
My switch is TL-SG108E.
The cable that gets the connection from the router to the switch is Cat.5E.

EDIT: On safe-boot with network I get the 500Mbps. So I already ruled out hardware failure, it's some configuration on windows.

Answer (score 2):

As booting in Safe Mode fixes the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application or driver is responsible for it.

Check first the driver for your network adapter. See if the Support website
of the computer manufacturer has a newer version of it.

Otherwise, to locate a problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system bootup or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required.

I would start with disabling any security package you have installed and any other
internet-watching products.